# Highcharts: Tooltip delay before display

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

On my highchart i need a delay before the series tooltip is displayed.

I defined a new refresh function with a timer to realize it. If the timer is ready i check if the mouse position. If it moved not that much the tooltip should appear.

```
function (H) {
              var timer = [];
              var mousePosition = {
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0
              };

              window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
                  mousePosition.x = event.pageX;
                  mousePosition.y = event.pageY;
              });

              var getMousePositionX = function () {
                  return mousePosition.x;
              };

              var clearTimer = function () {
                  timer = [];
              }

              H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'refresh', function (proceed) {
                  var mousePosX = getMousePositionX();
                  var delayForDisplay = this.chart.options.tooltip.delayForDisplay ? this.chart.options.tooltip.delayForDisplay : 1000;
                  timer[timer.length+1] = window.setTimeout(function () {
                      var currMousePosX = getMousePositionX();
                      if ((mousePosX >= currMousePosX - 5 && mousePosX <= currMousePosX + 5)) {
                          this.proceed.apply(this.tooltip, this.refreshArguments);
                          clearTimer();
                      }
                  }.bind({
                      refreshArguments: Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
                      chart: this.chart,
                      tooltip: this,
                      clearTimer: clearTimer,
                      proceed: proceed
                  }), delayForDisplay);
              });
          };
```

The problem I have is, that the hover holos have also a delay.

Here is a sample: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhta0byh/1/)

Any solutions for this issue?

Comment: I hope this example may help you with your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/az39das8/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński: That's exactly what I was looking for. You are amazing :)

Comment: Happy to read that my idea worked for you. I have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: Also here http://rudovjan.github.io/highcharts-tooltip-delay/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make new tooltip basing on your standard Highcharts tooltip and show it on your mouseover with some timeout:

```
load: function() {
  chart = this;
  this.myTooltip = new Highcharts.Tooltip(this, this.options.tooltip);
  this.tooltip.label.element.remove();
}


    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function(e) {
          var i = this.x;
          points = [];
          Highcharts.each(this.series.chart.series, function(s) {
            Highcharts.each(s.data, function(p) {
              if (p.x === i) {
                points.push(p)
              }
            })
          });
          myTooltip = chart.myTooltip;
          setTimeout(function() {
            myTooltip.refresh(points, e)
          }, 1000)

        }, mouseOut: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
        chart.myTooltip.hide();
          }, 1000)
        }
      }
    }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/az39das8/